# Testcafe get json response

Tags: jquery, html, testing, response, testcafe

Is there any way to get the JSON response that a button that testcafe clicks during a test produce? 
That button in the normal website makes an ajax request so I want to get the JSON off that request in testcafe.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible in the current version TestCafe (v0.14), but we have planned this feature: [Implement request hooks](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1341).

You can Subscribe to it to be notified about the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Request hooks have been implemented.

```
import { RequestHook } from 'testcafe';

class RequestReader extends RequestHook {
  constructor (requestFilterRules) {
    super(requestFilterRules, { includeBody: true });
  }
  async onRequest (event) {
    // ...
  }
  async onResponse (event) {
    const responseBody = JSON.parse(event.body.toString());
    console.log(responseBody);
  }
}
export const readerHook = new RequestReader(/api/);
```